# How to find Search input Element with selenium using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

How to find Element of a Search input with selenium using python

I tried many attempts and failed.

[image: HTML Element Code]

```
searchBar = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='__field__38__']")
searchBar.send_keys("admin@example.com")
```

How can I find this kind of elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```py
searchBar = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search by name']")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man you always give us the best and most relevant answers !

Comment: Not always, only when I know the answer :) You are welcome

Comment: can you check this one too ? thanks a lot
https://stackoverflow.com/q/69553153/4825921