# How to find a element after a search click checkbox in selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

After I search for a user in the search field, I get the user I searched
Now I need to select this user that shown in the list

I tried with xpath and did not find the element ! could you help ?

So after I search for that user I need to click the first result checkbox

[image: HTML Element code]

[image: Website screenshot]

what I tried:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[4]/main[1]/div[3]/div[2]/section[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]").click()

WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'azc-grid-cellContent') and(contains(text(),'{}'))]".format(email)))).click()
```

Edit: Added a new photo

[image]

Comment: Your xpath is absolute xpath which is brittle.  please share HTML in text format

Comment: please ask developer to add custom attributes, if your elements are like this. soon you will get disappoint on automation. add attribute like <div auto="checkbox">. this is the best way of doing automation.

Comment: @JayanthBala Im not the owner of the website im working on Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com/)

Comment: @cruisepandey How to past all html code in here ? its only allowing me pasting 30k words

Comment: Please upload in text format to file hosting web site and then share link with us here.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to click on the first presented result please try this:

```py
WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@aria-rowindex='1']//div[@data-bind]"))).click()
```

I'm not sure about this.
Need to see the actual web page with the dev tools for better suggestion...

Comment: can you help If I share my anydesk ?
I tried your suggestion , but I did not work.

And btw How to share all my html code ! StackOverflow is not allowing me past more than 30k

Comment: Anydesk is a good idea, but not when I work from the office and my boss is sitting behind me  so maybe tomorrow.